# Which one of the following groups is isomorphic to the group $G\ $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

> Let group $$G = \left \langle a,b,c\ |\ a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = 1, aba = bab, bcb = cbc, ac = ca \right \rangle.$$ Which one of the following groups is isomorphic to the group $G\ $?
>
> (1) $D_8,$ Dihedral group of order $8.$
>
> (2) $\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2.$
>
> (3) $S_3,$ Symmetric group of order $6.$
>
> (4) $S_4,$ Symmetric group of order $24.$

What I find is that $ab,ba,bc,cb$ are all distinct elements in $G$ of order $3.$ Moreover $ab$ and $ba,$ $bc$ and $cb$ are inverses of each other. Since $3$ doesn't divide $8,$ $G$ can't be isomorphic to $D_8$ or $(\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2).$ Also since $G$ has at least four distinct elements of order $3,$ it can't be isomorphic to $S_3$ as well. Hence the group $G$ has to be isomorphic to $S_4.$ So the last option is the only correct option.

But I can't able to show it explicitly that $(4)$ is indeed the correct option. Can anybody please check my reasoning above and suggest some technique to actually prove it explicitly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try to define a map $G\to S_4$ by $a\to (12),\ b\to (13), \ c\to (34)$

Comment: None of the answers that you have had prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $S_4$. They only prove that there is a surjective homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_4$. There is more work to do to prove that $\phi$ is injective. (Of course you can answer the question correctly simply by eliminating the other three choices, but you haven't really done that, because you haven't proved your assertion that $G$ has at least four elements of order 3.)

Comment: @Derek Holt I have proved it on my own. If you want I am ready to show you up my work. This is very straightforward.

Comment: @DerekHolt what I have shown is that $ab = (ba)^2, ba = (ab)^2$ by exploiting the relation $aba=bab.$ Similarly we can prove that $bc = (cb)^2, cb = (bc)^2$ by exploiting the relation $bcb=cbc.$ From here it's easy to see that all those four elements $ab,ba,bc, cb$ are all of order $3.$ Can they be equal?

Comment: To address this question first we observe that $ab \neq ba.$ For otherwise $aba = b \implies bab = b \implies ba = e \implies b = a^{-1} = a,$ a contradiction.  $ab \neq bc$ as well. For otherwise $bca = aba = bab.$ Since $ac = ca$ it follows that $ac = ab \implies a = b,$ again a contradiction.

Comment: $ab \neq cb$ for otherwise $cbc = bac \implies bcb = bac \implies ac = cb.$ So using the relation $ac = ca$ we find that $ca = cb \implies a = b,$ a contradiction. $ba$ and $bc$ are distinct for otherwise $a = c.$ I think now you will be convinced @Derek Holt.

Comment: No I am not convinced. Why is $a=b$ a contradiction? You haven't proved that $a \ne b$. You need a different type of argument to do that.

Comment: The other two things can be shown easily. If $ba = cb$ then $ab =  bc,$ which we proved already to be false. What next? $bc \neq cb.$ Right? But it can't be proved along the same lines as that of $ab \neq ba$ by exploiting the relation $bcb = cbc.$ Too easy!

Comment: Because they are assumed to be different elements @Derek Holt.

Comment: There is no such assumption stated in the question. The group $G$ is defined by a presentation, and some presentations define the trivial group.

Comment: No @Derek Holt in our course it has been stated firmly that whenever we are given a group generated by $n$ many elements we will always assume that all the elements of the generating set are distinct. For otherwise we can delete that element from the generating set and the remaining set of generators still generate the same group. Am I right?

Comment: If you are not convinced then please try to provide your own answer. This site is not for extended discussion or chatting. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am misleading you slightly, because the fact that there is a surjective homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_4$ does prove your statements about the elements of order 3, because their images under $\phi$ have order 3, and so they cannot be trivial. But to prove $G \cong S_4$ you would still need to prove that $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: You may have been told that you can assume that the generators in a presentation represent distinct elements, but unfortunately that is not always true.  For a silly example, consider the presentation $\langle a,b \mid a=b \rangle$.

Comment: @Derek Holt if we assume all the possibilities of $a,b,c$ then either $G \cong \{e\}$ or $\Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z$ (if $a = b \iff b = c$ and hence $G \cong \left \langle a \right \rangle$) or $G \cong S_3$ (if $a = c$ and hence $G \cong \left \langle b,c \right \rangle = \{e,b,c,bc,cb,bcb \}$) or there exists a surjective group homomorphism from $G \to S_4.$  The interesting fact is that $G \cong S_3$ is also a possibility which is what option $(3)$ tells. I am confused now. Which option should I take as the correct option? Is it $(3)$ or $(4)\ $? Oops... Can you please help me?

Comment: Though the example of the group $G$ what you gave is also generated by a single element say $a.$ Hence $G$ is cyclic. If $a = b$ and $G = \left \langle a,b \right \rangle$ then you can drop the role of one of the generators $a$ or $b$ as I have said in one of my comments above @Derek Holt.

Comment: I think we are discussing too many things at once, so let's get back to the problem. Since, using the answers below, you have proved that there is a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $S_4$, we know that $|G| \ge 24$, which immediately eliminates (1),  (2) and (3). So you know that (4) must be correct, but to prove it, you would need to prove that $\phi$ is injective. I will try and prove that in a new answer.

Comment: @Derek Holt $|G| \geq 24$ iff $a,b,c$ are all distinct. Right? Also if you let $b = e$ and $a \neq b$ with $a,b \neq e$ then $G$ becomes a commutative group which is isomorphic to the Klein's-4-group.

Comment: That's correct (because both statements are true!), but the point is that the answers below tell you how to prove that $|G| \ge 24$.

Comment: I have edited my comment. Please have a look at it @Derek Holt. Coming back after some time. Playing chess right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115089/discussion-between-anacardium-and-derek-holt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have said in my comments, the other answers show that there is a surjective homomorphism $G \to S_4$. To prove that this is an isomorphism, it is enough to prove that $|G| \le 24$, which can be done as follows.

Let $H = \langle a,b \rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$ and $b$.
I am assuming you know that $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=1, aba=bab \rangle$ defines the dihedral group of order $6$, so $|H| \le 6$, and it is enough to prove that $|G:H| \le 4$.

To do that, we shall prove that $G = H \cup Hc \cup Hcb \cup Hcba$, and to do that it is sufficent to prove that if we multiply any of these cosets by any of the generators $a,b,c$ of $G$, then we will get another one of these cosets. So let's do that.

1. Multiply coset $H$ by $a,b,c$: $Ha=H$, $Hb=H$, $Hc=Hc$.

2. Multiply coset $Hc$ by $a,b,c$: $Hca=Hac=Hc$, $Hcb=Hcb$, $Hcc=H$.
3. Multiply coset $Hcb$ by $a,b,c$: $Hcba=Hcba$, $Hcbb=Hc$, $Hcbc=Hbcb=Hcb$.
4. Multiply coset $Hcba$ by $a,b,c$: $Hcbaa=Hcb$, $Hcbab=Hcaba=Hacba=Hcba$, $Hcbac=Hcbca=Hbcba=Hcba$.

This proof generalizes to similar presentations of $S_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Dihedral group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3,$ the symmetric group in three letters. If $H = D_6$ then $|H| = 6.$ Why do you write $|H| \leq 6\ $?

Comment: Very nicely argued! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If we consider all the possibilities for $a,b,c$ then there are $5$-groups upto isomorphism with which the group $G$ is isomorphic to. They are the trivial group $\{e \}, \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z, \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z, S_3$ and $S_4.$

Comment: You seem to be a little unclear about the meaning of a group defined by a presentation. Any presentation defines a unique group. So $G$ cannot possibly be isomorphic to both of two non-isomorphic groups.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. What I was trying to say is that for each possibility of the triples $(a,b,c)$ and their orders (observe that their orders could have been $1$ as well in which case any of the generators may as well be identity) $G$ represents a unique group out of the five groups I have mentioned (in my above comment) upto isomorphism. What's wrong in my statement?

Comment: I can only repeat my previous comment - a presentation defines a unique group. Your presentation defines a group  $G$ that is isomorphic to $S_4$, so the orders of the generators cannot be $1$. All of the generators in that group have order $2$.

Comment: How do you know that? The relation $x^2 = e$ in a group will be satisfied by identity element as well. Am I right? Also what you have said in one of your earlier comments (before posting this answer) that it may so happen two or all of $a,b,c$ are equal. Then how do you disagree that, I wonder! You are repeating self contradictory arguments again and again. Are you deliberately trying to make me confused?

Comment: Yes I said that it can happen that two generators in a group presentation can be equal. It doesn't happen in this example, but the point I was making is that you cannot assume that it does not make it happen - you have to prove it. Again, if we know that $x^2=e$, then it can happen that $x=e$, but in this particular example that does not happen. I know that $a^2 \ne e$ in this example, because we have proved that there is an isomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to $S_4$, and that $\phi(a) = (1,2)$. So we cannot have $a^2=e$ because that would imply that $\phi(a) = e$.

Comment: I am sorry, I promise that I am not deliberately trying to confuse you. But it seems to me that you are already confusaed about what exactly the notation $G = \langle a,b,c \mid \ldots \rangle$ means.

Comment: You said that in this case you have a surjective group homomorphism from $G$ to $S_4.$ But that can only be done under the assumption that all of $a,b,c$ are distinct. Right? How do you guarantee that? It may so happen that $a=c$ and $b$ and $c$ are distinct elements of order $2$ in $G$ which will generate the generate the group $S_3.$  How can you deny that?

Comment: No there is no such assumption that all of $a,b,c$ are distinct. You have it the wrong way round. The fact that there is a surjective homomorphism onto $S_4$ proves that $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct.

Comment: How do you prove that surjection if we assume $a = b = c = e\ $?

Comment: I apologise for being rude. But the size of $G$ cannot change. $G$ is a fixed and well-defined mathematical object.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Try letting $a=(12),b=(23)$ and $c=(34)$.  Try to prove that $S_4=\langle a,b,c\rangle$, and that they satisfy the given relations.

Comment: Hmm. I also thought in that way. So it is enough to generate all the remaining three transpositions of $S_4.$ Right?

Comment: Yes,  that would obviously work!

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I find that $$(2\ 3) (1\ 2) (2\ 3) = (1\ 3), (3\ 4) (1\ 3) (3\ 4) = (1\ 4), (1\ 2) (1\ 4) (1\ 2) = (2\ 4).$$ Hence done!

Comment: Right you are...

Comment: So what you had was a presentation for $S_4$.

Comment: Yeah! Right. Is it related to representation theory? I don't know it though but heard about it.

Comment: Representations are different than presentations.  The former use linear algebra to model groups, and I don't know much about it.  The latter is found in combinatorial group theory, which I know a little about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115083/discussion-between-anacardium-and-chris-custer).

Answer (score 0):

That $a^2=b^2=c^2=1$ suggests that we try transpositions. $ac=ca$ suggests most easily that $a=(12),c=(34)$; because $b$ does not commute with either $a$ or $c$, we try $b=(23)$. And indeed these assignments work; because these are transpositions spanning every element of a four-element set, they generate $S_4$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. $S_4$ is spanned by the cycles $(12),(13)$ and $(34)$.